# Using Angular material2 table with an http service

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an http service which retrieves some data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getData(searchterm) {

      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/product/' + searchterm).map((res: Response) => res.json());

     }

}
```

I know would like to populate a table from the material framework with this service using pagination.

Reading the docs at https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination in the examples they use their own database in the component ts file to generate some hardcoded values. I have tried to modify this code to use my http service but I have been unable to get it to work due to the fact I am not 100% following the flow of the example (e.g do I need the datasource or can I take this out?). I am looking for the most basic example of how to populate a table with a http service which then allows pagination.

What I have tried so far:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';


import { MatPaginator, MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material';

import { SearchService } from './../search.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  providers: [WorklistService, SearchService]
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger)
  autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

  dataSource = new ExampleDataSource();

  constructor() { }

  OnSearchEnterPressed(event) {
    this.dataSource.populateTable();
  }

}

export interface Data {

  id: string;

  name: string;
}

var httpdata: any[];

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  populateTable(searchterm) {
    this.searchService.getData('somevaluetotsendtotheservice').subscribe(data => {
      httpdata = data;
      this.connect();
    });
  }

  connect(): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.of(httpdata);
  }

  disconnect() { }
}
```

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Updated: This is what I have tried to far to just get the data to show (without the pagination yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official material example in GitHub this should help you with the implementation.
Here is the link: [table-http](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/97447f93498c0aafb746cfa5208c84b2d9fc648a/src/material-examples/table-http)

Comment: That example is available in the documentation: https://material2-docs-dev.firebaseapp.com/components/table/examples

Comment: They actually came out with a new release yesterday which does this now. Great timing!

Comment: Please add at least the relevant parts of the linked resource, as links can die/change